# Android Studio graphics garbled

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu-22.04

I recently upgraded my Virtual Box's Ubuntu to 22.04.2 LTS but now my Android Studio is all garbled when I launch it.  Visual Studio Code runs and displays fine, but not Android Studio [image: Android Studio Garbled Image]

I'm guessing the upgrade removed required files, but I'm not sure how to troubleshoot so I can resolve it.  I also created a new Virtual
Box running Ubuntu 22.10 and that has the same issue, except Visual Studio Code has the same problem too.  However, that was a fresh install of Ubuntu and then adding Android Studio and VS Code on top of it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I misspoke, my Visual Studio Code app has the title garbled so now it has the same problem as my Ubuntu 22.10 VBox installation.  VS Code title is garbled and Android Studio entire application is garbled.

Comment: I have the same issues. Do you resolved ?

Comment: @aeroxr1 No, never resolved.